# making different layouts for different screen density

Tags: android-studio

I have made this layout for a normal device, and I edit it on the normal device (Nexus 5), but when I run the layout on the emulator, it looks not good although I run it in the same device(Nexus 5) as the picture below show. I need to know where is the problem?)

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvhYp.jpg)

Comment: There's possibly some issue in your layout that's causing the problem. The emulator's great for getting things going quickly but you can bugs on either that or your real device. Try you app on a different emulator and/or another real device. You coutd post your layout here for more feedback.

Comment: @RichardNixon, I have tried to run it on my real device S6 edge, but it looks terrible. Here is a picture of it [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYRcQ.jpg). And here is a screenshot for the layout code [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30W5C.jpg)